# Delete all thumbnails & regenerate them?

Tags: images, media, thumbnails

Is there any safe way to delete all thumbnails and then regenerate them.

I tried to use plugins like [Thumbnail Cleaner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/thumbnail-cleaner/), but after using it + regenerating via popular thumbnail regenerator plugin; I have found most important thumbnails are not generated. Rather many important images and thumbnails are deleted like logo, testimonials images, blog thumbnails, some media thumbnails, elementor's thumbnails etc.

Comment: thumbnail cleaner hasn't been updated in 5 years and isn't listed in the .org plugin repo unless you go to it directly, you should try a newer better maintained plugin, and you should use a single plugin to regenerate without "cleaning"

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to delete them first? You can use Regenerate Thumbnails if you need to generate new image sizes after switching themes or registering a new image size.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

This plugin also gives you an option to delete images related to unregistered sizes.

Note: the plugin is not tested with the last few releases of Wordpress

Comment: Actually in one of my client's website, there are lots of thumbnails which are not being used in live site. Also there are many images he has uploaded but not used in the post. I tried various method like media cleaner pro etc. but I guess there is no proper method to manage media in wordpress yet.